# Do CFLs have a significant impact on your light bill?

Tags: economics, compact-fluorescent-lamps

I just moved into my own apartment, and I've taken quite an interest in being as energy-efficient as possible (simply because, hey - I'm paying the electricity bill now!).

I've been wondering - are [Compact fluorescent lamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_fluorescent_lamp) (CFLs) as efficient as they claim to be? I detest the light that they give off, but if they're significantly cheaper to use (especially in contrast to how expensive they are in comparison to normal bulbs), then I might be persuaded to pick up a few.

I work almost constantly, so I probably don't use more than 3 or 4 hours of electric light daily, anyway.

So, is it worth the investment (and inconvenience)? I'm just a bit skeptical of something that claims to save me money by being 4-6 times the cost of the alternative.

Comment: New generation CFLs have much more cozy light than the old ones. Be sure to get a [“warm” glowing bulb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CFBulbs.jpg). They are more expensive though.

Comment: I actually did a test of this with my father when they were first becoming widely available. The answer was, yes. And I suspect even more so today. However, the reality is that other bulbs give off heat, so if you are in a cold climate where you always have the heat on, your heater will have to work that much harder, offsetting the cost. Also, Nice avatar.

Comment: They will last longer and use less electricity.  The electricity is quantifiable, given your electricity rate.  The lasting longer is going to be more difficult to measure.

Comment: It will make a difference on your *light* bill yes. But if you have electric heating, it may not make a big difference on your *electricity* bill as you may have to heat more instead. If you live in a hot climate and use air conditioners a lot, low energy lightbulbs of any sort should be a good investment (although I prefer LED, as they are less full of poisons).

Comment: @Lennart, you should really make that an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: I believe i have seen studies that show that CFLs also dim over time.  Each cycle reduces both their brightness and lifespan, so a simple test of "I bought a new one, it produces X lumens on Y watts, therefore it saves me $Z over its lifetime as compared to an incandescent with the same lumen rating" are too simplistic.  After a period of time shorter than the advertised life, the bulb may be too dim to be practical, and would then need to be replaced.

Comment: @Kevin: Then I would get spanked by the moderators for not including references to scientific papers showing that. Facts and logic are not reliable sources on this site.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro Regarding heating: I got an extremely awesome deal on my apartment, and heat is rolled in to my (extremely low) rent, so that's not an issue.

Comment: @kivetros: Then low energy lamps will save you money, and Rusty's answer is relevant for you. At least if you bring the lamps with you when you move. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If saving ~$500usd/year is significant then yes.**

[image: CFL v LED v INC]

Source: [Las Vegas Strip: An Energy Consumption Nightmare](http://green.thefuntimesguide.com/2007/04/las_vegas_energy_use.php)

**Other tips:**

1. **Smarter Switches**
   Install motion-detecting switches that turn off lights when a room is empty.
2. **CPU Myth**
   Shut down your PC if it
   will be idle more than 2 hours. The
   idea that turning a computer off and
   on shortens its life is a relic of
   the mainframe era.
3. **Bright Idea**
   Use compact fluorescent
   bulbs. New models illuminate just as
   well as incandescents -- and operate
   on just over one quarter of the
   power.
4. **Cold Truth**
   Keep your refrigerator or
   freezer full; it operates more
   efficiently that way. Low on food?
   Keep a container of ice in the
   freezer.

Source: [Popular Mechanics](http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/improvement/energy-efficient/4217078?click=main_sr)

Comment: Keep in mind that CFL lifetimes are *greatly* reduced when used for brief periods of time, but often. While constant evening-time lighting is generally on for the duration of evening activities, in places like the bathroom, where the bulb is on for 1-10 minutes at a time (but can turn on 10-20 times a day depending on the number of tenants), the energy benefit of switching to CFL is offset by the shortened lifespan.

Comment: Huh? For incandescent they quote 3285 KWh per year is about 9 KWh per day or 400W of lights turned on for 24 hours (or more lights for a shorter time).  If you simply turn lights out when not in the room, doesn't that seem like a bit much?

Comment: @Paul: Yeah, that's a bit high. They also forgot to lower the heating bill by 9 KWh per day. :)

Comment: Just the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you very much - you've made up my mind.

Comment: @Lennart: Yeah, because you pay for heating in the summertime...

Comment: @Ernie: In some places you do, yeah. The point being that this chart is only valid in places where you never heat (and for that matter, never use air conditioning).

Comment: This answer is highly misleading: The chart assumes 150 bulb hours per day, while the question suggests 3 to 4 bulb hours per day. So the electricity savings will be closer to $10/year than $500

Comment: @eigensheep: That answer is also six years old -- we should be looking at LED's today, which are even more efficient...